# Intellij Idea 13 ultimate performance slow, lags while typing

Tags: intellij-idea, intellisense, intellij-13

I've googled and tried all SO answers, but none seems to be working for me.

The CPU usage remains low when inactive, as soon as I start typing, it jumps and takes a few seconds to see what I'm typing. Should be some kind of inspection/intellisense, but disabling it makes IDE useless (IDE means intellisense to me), although I'm willing to give it a try and have already tried the below things, but nothing seems to be working for me.

I've tried the following things :

```
1. -Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50

2. Disabled Git & Subversion plugin

3. Disabled "Probable Bugs" in settings -> Inspection

4. Made sure that I'm running Idea64.exe and changing idea64.exe.vmoptions

5. Created a system variable IDEA_JDK_64 to point to JDK7Update60 

6. Disabled "AutoPopupCodeCompletion" in Editor->CodeCompletion and changed "CaseSensitiveCompletion" to None.

7. Added {userdir}/.intellij and {project}/.idea to Anti-Virus scan exclusion
```

Comment: Just make a CPU Snapshot and report an issue. JetBrains will usuallly tell you what to do, and they will fix it, or don't you want it to be fixed? https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/29983118-Reporting-performance-problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a discussion with Intellij Support Team

The issue was with only large files `(8k+ lines of .js code)`. Probably, because of system hardware limits.

When I worked with files having less lines of code, it behaved fine.

Comment: Yea, that's kind of annoying though when you're working with JS frameworks that have tens of thousands of lines of code. I'm using an iMac i7 with 16GB Ram and it *still* struggles after being open for an hour or two. IMVHO IntelliJ has some pretty serious memory leakage that they need to fix. It's been a problem as long as I've been using it (since version 10).

Comment: @Jangla I just recently moved to a core i7 with 16GB RAM and files having 8-13k lines of js code still hangs. :( Will create another ticket. - https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/requests/42033

Comment: just got a reply https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-58130, seems like they've fixed it in v14

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but I just had similar issue and googling pops this page so it might help someone else in the future.

I am running IntelliJ IDEA 16.1 and writing javascipt was unbearably slow. At the end I tried File | Invalidate Caches/Restart which solved the issue.

Comment: Invalidating the cache worked for me. Only downside when doing it is that you lose all your local history.

Comment: I had a lot of memory remaining and the files were not that large (max of 1000 lines). Obviously, it was something else. Thank you, it seems to be fixed now.